# Changing keyboard language not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I have my keyboard set up to be able to switch to various languages.  Mostly it seems to work, but for some reason, at times it does not.  Today I tried switching it to Spanish and then some of the other languages I use and none worked. ่Then I took a screen shot for this very post and suddenly it started to type in the selected language.  Any idea what could cause the problem and how to fix it?